# Backup workspace without local copies of remote git repositories

Tags: backup, git

I would like to backup my workspace without backing up all the content of git repositories that are online available anyway.

So I think of something like, that I could backup only the file `.git/config` in each folder, so if I want to restore some project from the backup, I only have to go into the folder and fetch the current state.

Which files would I have to backup to be able to restore a project?

(Perfectly would be a routine that checks if all files I have locally are pushed to a remote and if it finds local changes thoe files will be backed up.)

Answer (score 0):

> So I think of something like, that I could backup only the file `.git/config` in each folder, so if I want to restore some project from the backup, I only have to go into the folder and fetch the current state.

That's not enough. You will also need to back up, at least:

- All commits that have been made locally but not (yet) pushed to any remote repository
- The files in the working directory or index that have not been staged or committed
- All Git stashes

You can use `git bundle` to get partway to your goal. For example:

1. Commit everything in the index and everything that is dirty in the working directory, for example to remporary branches.
2. Convert all stashes to real branches
3. Run this:

   ```
   git bundle create /tmp/foo $(git branch -r $(git branch -r | awk '{ print $1 }')
   ```

Now back up `/tmp/foo` and `.git/config`.

This is neither very automatic nor do I guarantee that it doesn't miss something. I don't recommend that you actually do it.

Or check out [Converting git repository to shallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698759/converting-git-repository-to-shallow) That might be closer to what you are looking for.